# Table displaying wrong in Firefox, table goes horizontal?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm having trouble with a table that has images, and all is great browsing with Chrome and IE but the trouble starts with Firefox. The table instead going vertically goes horizontal from the second row and so for. Can anybody tell me what is the problem and how can I fix this? Here is a link to the [page](http://shoppingkatalog.com/product/view/129/1317.html).

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set rowspan="1", that was the solution in this case

Answer (score 2):

For one, you have two `td`s in the top row and only one in the rest.

Also, what is this!? No opening `tr`.

```
<table class="prod_buttons">
    <td id = "jshop_image_loading" style = "display:none"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Fix [these errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://shoppingkatalog.com/product/view/129/1317.html&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) and your issue will probably be resolved.

Comment: i found a fix, I need do set rowspan=1, is there a CSS equivalent?

Comment: No. CSS is for styling, `rowspan` and `colspan` change the structure of the table.

Answer (score 0):

It's a difference between the interface of the different browsers.  Unfortunatly, browsers do not have a standardized version so we can develop one application that works on all, but instead they build them based on their own standards so web developers run into this problem a lot.  The only way to "fix" this is to detect the kind of browser you are operating in, and switch the way you output the code based on that.

Comment: No it's not. It's errors in markup. All browsers will display a table correctly if the markup is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove 'display' style from your table rows:
None of comments below solved my issue.